# javascript async sweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

So i have to try to create an async function that waits for a user input before returning, however, I am not quite sure how to do it:

```
  async createAlert() {
      return await swal({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
          cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
          reverseButtons: true
      }).then(function (result) {
          //user has answered we want to return the result
      })
  }
```

this jquery creates the following popup:

[image]

When the user presses either button the (`then`) part of the code is executed and here i want to return that result

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
async createAlert() {
    try{
      let result = await swal({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
          cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
          reverseButtons: true
      });
      // SUCCESS
      return result;
    }catch(e){
        // Fail!
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about inputs? ```let result = await swal('ACAD Helper',"Amount to Submit:", {
        content: "input",
      });```